# Matrix transformation scale with multiple objects

Tags: actionscript-3, matrix, scale

I have array of tiles and they are drawn on my "canvas".

I know how to transform my canvas to scale from it's center:

```
var m:Matrix = new Matrix();
m.translate(-centerX, -centerY);
m.scale(scaleX, scaleY);
m.translate(centerX, centerY);
```

This will scale and translate tile to its x,y

```
var m:Matrix = new Matrix();
m.translate(_tile.x,_tile.y);
m.scale(_scale, _scale);
```

But how do I scale all my bitmap tiles from center while I'm drawing them on "canvas"

Answer (score 0):

This code shows how to scale and center tile bitmapdata (tile_1 is a "(0,0)" arranged bitmap) using the BitmapData.draw method:

```
var tile:BitmapData = new tile_1();
var canvas:BitmapData = new BitmapData(1000, 1000, true, 0x00FFFFFF);
var scale:Number = 2;
canvas.draw(tile, new Matrix(scale, 0, 0, scale, -tile.width*scale/2, -tile.height*scale/2));
```

If you use another technique for drawing tile please describe it more detailed.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My problem is bit different.
I have 100x100 array of tiles and I put them on my "canvas" with draw.
I use transformation to scroll my tiles while I'm drawing them.
I want to learn how to scale all the tiles depending on their position on canvas from center.

Comment: What do you mean by the "scale all the tiles depending on their position on canvas from center." ? My code scale tile and draws it, you also can add translation to the give point into the drawing matrix or I didn't get your question.